# In C# can casting a Char to Int32 produce a negative value?

Tags: c#, casting

Or is it always guaranteed to be positive for all possible Chars?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's guaranteed to be non-negative.

`char` is an *unsigned* 16-bit value.

From section 4.1.5 of the C# 4 spec:

> The `char` type represents unsigned 16-bit integers with values between 0 and 65535. The set  of possible values for the `char` type corresponds to the Unicode character set. Although `char` has the same representation as `ushort`, not all operations permitted on one type are permitted on the other.

Answer (score 2):

Since the range of [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) is U+0000 to U+ffff, then a cast to an `Int32` will always be positive.

Answer (score 2):

> Each 16-bit value ranges from hexadecimal 0x0000 through 0xFFFF and is
>   stored in a Char structure.

[Char Structure - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x9h8tsay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

There you  can see, that Char is a 16 bit value in the range of U+0000 to U+ffff. If you cast it to a Int32, there should be no negative value.

Answer (score 0):

`char` can be inplicitly converted to `ushort` and `ushort` range is `0 to 65,535` so its always positive